# Form values don't send when file selected

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core-mvc

If I submit my form without selecting a file, I can see that the `office` param is sent through with the correct office name

However, after selecting a file from the `file` input and then submitting, both params come through as `null`

what gives?

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upload(string office, string path)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new{office = office});
}
```

View

```
<div class="row">
    <form method="POST" asp-action="Upload" asp-controller="FloorPlan" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input class="form-control" name="office" type="hidden" value="@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["office"]"  />
        <input class="form-control" name="path" type="file" />
        <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your action method needs to use `IFormFile` interface to access the uploaded file through model binding. Check out the guide at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to junkangli's comment I now have this working controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upload(string office, IFormFile file)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new{office = office});
}
```